# Can't make more than one Rect per scope

Tags: c++, sdl

Okay, so when I make multiple rects in the same scope and I access one of one's members, 
all other rects (in the same scope) become inaccessable.

As in, if I do;

```
SDL_Rect* name;
SDL_Rect* otherName;
name->x = 7;
```

Now attempting, for instance, `otherName->h = 10` will crash *on that line*.

It's unrelated to the order the rects are declared in too -

```
SDL_Rect* otherName;
SDL_Rect* name;
name->x = 7;
```

Accessing otherName still crashes.

Comment: Is this *all* the important code; IOW is there anything between `SDL_Rect* otherName;` and `otherName->h = 10` you'd like to show us?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils apparently there wasn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you are declaring pointers to SDL_Rects but you haven't allocated any memory for them.
You should do something like:

```
SDL_Rect* otherName = new SDL_Rect(...);
SDL_Rect* name =  new SDL_Rect(...);
name->x = 7;
otherName->h = 10;
```

Or just allocate on the stack:

```
SDL_Rect otherName;
SDL_Rect name;
name.x = 7;
otherName.h = 10;
```